# Combo Box selected Item is updated to the model property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Setting attribute to the model property which is bounded to the combo box for selected item after assigning null is not updated back to the model property. e.g: In our scenario we update the Item source and selected item dynamically. Here we set the selected item as null afterwards we handles null and rollback to first item of the combo box. The view got updates properly but the model still holds null only. Please find the below code for reference.

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<string> Xitems;
    string Xselected;

    public ObservableCollection<string> XItems
    {
        get
        {
            return Xitems;
        }
        set
        {
            Xitems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string XSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return Xselected;
        }
        set
        {
            Xselected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ObservableCollection<string> Yitems;
    string Yselected;

    public ObservableCollection<string> YItems
    {
        get
        {
            return Yitems;
        }
        set
        {
            Yitems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string YSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return Yselected;
        }
        set
        {
            Yselected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool isModified { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    static MainWindow()
    {

    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        viewModel.XItems = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Thadam", "Comali", "Kaithi", "Thuppakki", "Kaththi" };
        viewModel.XSelected = "Kaththi";
        viewModel.YItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "B", "A", "C" };
        viewModel.YSelected = "A";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if((sender as ComboBox).IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            viewModel.isModified = false;
            viewModel.YItems = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Banana", "Apple", "Ice" };
            viewModel.YSelected = "Apple";
            viewModel.isModified = true;
            viewModel.YSelected = null;

        }
    }
    private void ComboBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (viewModel.isModified)
        {
            (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0;
            MessageBox.Show(viewModel.YSelected);
        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
 <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding XItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding XSelected}"  SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding YSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox2_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Note that the message box still show the null only.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should handle this in the viewmodel instead of in code behind, perhaps creating a new ObservableCollection breaks the binding. Try clearing the YItems list and adding the new items instead of creating a new list.

Comment: @HotTowelie Handle in viewmodel is not a generic solution. we have a custom combo box so it should handle in the event only.I check by clear and add the collection items also,that the same problem still happens

Comment: setting `SelectedIndex` directly on ComboBox object may be breaking data binding. The alternative way would be to do `viewModel.YSelected = viewModel.YItems[0];` instead.